# Redis StackExchange batching and transactions

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to understand the nitty gritty details of Redis StackExchange.

1.
If I create a batch, and update a key and also set expiration of that key.
Could that execute out of order when sent to redis, so that the expiration is set on a non-existing key before the update is made?
e.g.

```
batch.ListRightPushAsync(myKey, payload.ToByteArray());
batch.KeyExpireAsync(myKey, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

Should I use a transaction for this instead?

2.
The API for batches and transactions feels a bit catch 22 to use, you first have to execute it and then await the tasks.
There is a `WaitAll` void blocking method on the `IDatabase` interface.

Is there any difference to use this instead of `Task.WhenAll`?
I assume there has to be as the clever people who made the lib would not just randomly add blocking operations for no reason.

If I ingest large amounts of telemetry, e.g. logs and metrics. and I want to write this to redis as performant as possible.
Do I benefit from first buffering these and then sending them in a batch(or transaction)?

3.
If the StackExchange API throws timeout exceptions while processing such batch/transaction, does it mean that the data was lost. or just that it took too long waiting but the data will still be written?

In such case, I assume retries would be harmful as various operations might or might not have been applied to the data already?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **batches** are a way to send a sequence of commands through a StackExchange.Redis multiplexer with the guarantee of not having any other command external to that sequence sent in-between those ones. Batches do not exist in Redis itself and, even within batches, the server can interleave other commands sent by other clients with your own sequence of commands.

On the other side, **transactions** are handled by Redis itself in an atomic way and there are [multiple commands](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/) you can use to deal with them.

> If I create a batch, and update a key and also set expiration of that key. Could that execute out of order when sent to redis, so that the expiration is set on a non-existing key before the update is made?

Nope, the order of commands is preserved.

> Should I use a transaction for this instead?

It depends: if you wish to execute your commands in an atomic way then yes, use a transaction instead.

> 2. The API for batches and transactions feels a bit catch 22 to use, you first have to execute it and then await the tasks. There is a WaitAll void blocking method on the IDatabase interface.
>
> Is there any difference to use this instead of Task.WhenAll?

`RedisBase.WaitAll()` invokes `Task.WaitAll()` but times out after the configured  timeout:

- [RedisDatabase source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/620c28105f029105e40c35b186043712b33dee04/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisBase.cs#L41)
- [ConnectionMultiplexer source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/02c29ef8e8ddf8de9556c113a8a6fb1563f46a83/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs#L450)

> If I ingest large amounts of telemetry, e.g. logs and metrics. and I want to write this to redis as performant as possible. Do I benefit from first buffering these and then sending them in a batch(or transaction)?

Generally speaking no, at the end of the day every command ends up in the connection multiplexer and SE.Redis is very smart about how/when to send data, even using pipelines automatically under the covers.

> 3. If the StackExchange API throws timeout exceptions while processing such batch/transaction, does it mean that the data was lost. or just that it took too long waiting but the data will still be written?

I think both cases are possible and would suggest to design your architecture  for failure where it makes sense.

> In such case, I assume retries would be harmful as various operations might or might not have been applied to the data already?

SE.Redis has a configurable [backlog/retry policy](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/528d732f4daf2742e46d6fdad006e0e735c49abf/src/StackExchange.Redis/BacklogPolicy.cs) which you may want to configure the behavior of the library in this scenario.